# Jquery Generating HTML button conflict when generate html with append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on multiple choice form where a user can add an input field for a question, Means that if a question one answer then a user can add another ansewer input field by clicking on a button.
Like wise :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".addChoices"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="duration">Answer</label><div class="col-md-6"><input id="duration" name="answer[]" type="password" placeholder="Answer" class="input input-md"> <input type="checkbox" name="correct"> Correct </div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

This is working, But i also want then a user can add whole another question which i have wrote the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".questions"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_question_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="component addChoices"><!-- Password input--><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="duration">Question</label><div class="col-md-8"><input id="duration" name="duration" type="password" placeholder="Question" class="input input-md"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="duration">Answer</label><div class="col-md-6"><input id="duration" name="answer[]" type="password" placeholder="Answer" class="input input-md"><input type="checkbox" name="correct"> Correct &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: blue">Delete Choice</span></div></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="duration"></label><div class="col-md-6"><button class="add_field_button">Add Choices</button></div></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

Now the issue is that the first code have a button `add_field_button` which then again adds in the question add section. The one page have two button with same name using by Jquery.

The conflict should be eliminate.

Comment: You can make 1st button invisible?

Comment: How ??? @Banzay

Comment: What is the problem? don't you need a button to add choices in the first question and another button to add choices in the second question?

Comment: When the second question generates it also generates the button again with same name, That is the problem the button name should not be name for two questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which name do they have? Anyway you may give initial id to 1st button, say `id="btn1"`, than generate different `id`-s for new buttons, based on "text box count" value, and also hide previous button Like here:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  x=1;  //initlal text box count
});

$(".add_question_button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addform();    
});

$(".questions").on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    });

function addform(e){ //on add input button click
    var max_fields      = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".questions"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_question_button"); //Add button ID

        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="component addChoices">
<!-- Password input--><div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="duration">Question</label>
<div class="col-md-8"><input id="duration" name="duration" type="password" placeholder="Question" class="input input-md"></div></div>
<div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="duration">Answer</label>
<div class="col-md-6"><input id="duration" name="answer[]" type="password" placeholder="Answer" class="input input-md"><input type="checkbox" name="correct"> Correct &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color: blue">Delete Choice</span></div></div></div>
<div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="duration"></label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<button id="btn'+x+'" class="add_question_button" onclick="javascript:addform()">Add Choices</button></div></div>'); //add input box

  $("#btn"+(x-1)).hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. But my first block of code generates input fields  below question input field . Now i want to create new question along with the current one with same functionality of answer input field below the newly generated question. And both of the add choice buttons should be visible. You got me ?

Comment: I think  you can remove string `$("#btn"+(x-1)).hide();` and to proccess button objects via their unique `id`-s by  way you want.